# object-level validation in django serializers does not recognize function

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

```
class serializer_blahblah(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for ProfileUsefulRecommendations."""

    profile_id = serializers.UUIDField()
    recommendation_id = serializers.UUIDField()

    class Meta:
        """Meta class."""

        fields = (
            "id",
            "profile_id",
    ...
```

everything works perfectly with this serializer, however I decided to add object-level validation
Here is what happens:

```
    def validate(self, data):
        recommendation_id = str(data["recommendation_id"])
        print("recommendation: ", recommendation_id)
        validate_recommendation_id(recommendation_id=recommendation_id)
        print(validate_recommendation_id(recommendation_id=recommendation_id))
        return data
```

Print out:

```
recommendation:  3a232d0d-0705-4775-8bae-0e2f3d69c96c
```

It does not even recognize the function....

However, if I use exactly same function in individual field serializer, it goes well. But shortly speaking I need it as a object-level

ADDED the code of function:

```
def validate_recommendation_id(recommendation_id):
    try:
        Recommendation.objects.get(id=recommendation_id)
    except Recommendation.DoesNotExist as exception:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
            {f"{recommendation_id}": "does not exist"}
        ) from exception
    return recommendation_id
```

Comment: Please, can you add the code of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually guys, I have come up with solution as such.
Instead of validation function, I defined

```
Class CheckIfObjectHasId(queryset, lookup_object)
```

which later I called in serializers:

```
class serializer_blahblah(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for ProfileUsefulRecommendations."""

    profile_id = serializers.UUIDField(
        validators=[
             CheckIfObjectHasId(queryset=Profile.object.all(), lookup_object="id"
        ]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how you add validation per field.

```
class serializer_blahblah(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    recommendation_id = serializers.UUIDField()

    def validate_recommendation_id(self, recommendation_id):
        return recommendation_id
```

You don't call it in `validate` method.

Comment: as I mentioned that way works but, I need it to do in validation

Comment: I have couple of ids and believe if I create each infield function it would be redundant, therefore I believe validation() function is to proceed with... However why does it not call a function?

Comment: `recommendation_id = serializers.UUIDField()` you clearly have one id. I don't think I can help you as I don't understand what's the problem.

Comment: Actually no, I have two ids. Also probably you know that I can edit the code before posting here, therefore I removed other fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
 `def run_validate(self, data):
         if data['min_pay'] >= data['max_pay']:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({'message': 'max_pay cannot be less than min_pay'})
    else:
        return super().validate(data)`def run_validate(self, data):
```

try with this , this will work

and if you want to add for more field validation in a same model, u can write another 'if' statement inside same method, if you write another run_validate(), you will get error